# Uploading Image in Safari not working

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, safari, image-uploading

I am using native javascript methods to upload image to an Express server. There are two types of uploads in my application.

1. Uploading file object taken from `<input type=file>`
2. Uploading image drawn taken from `<canvas>`

I have no problems with the first type of upload for firefox, chrome and safari. File image is uploading correctly and I am able to view the file that was uploaded to the server.

However, I have a problem with the second type of upload. I am not able to upload the file correctly using a safari browser. It will always result in a 0 byte file in the server. But it is working fine on both firefox and chrome.

Here are snippets of my code:

```
const content = canvasRef.toDataURL()
const file = convertDataURLToFile(content, "signature.png");
fileUploadHelper(file, fileUploadUrl(), "signature");

function convertDataURLToFile (file, fileName) {
    const blobBin = window.atob(file.split(",")[1]);
    const array = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < blobBin.length; i++) {
        array.push(blobBin.charCodeAt(i));
    }
    return new window.File([new Uint8Array(array)], fileName, {type: "image/png"});
};

function fileUploadHelper (file, url, inputType) {
    const xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
    const formData = new window.FormData();
    formData.append("file", file);
    xhr.open("POST", `${url}&documentType=${inputType}`);
    xhr.send(formData);
};
```

Express snippet:

```
app.post("/fileUpload", function (req, res) {
    req.pipe(req.busboy);
    req.busboy.on("file", function (fieldname, file, filename) {
        file.on("data", function (data) {
            console.log(data.length);
        });
        var fstream = fs.createWriteStream("./tempFiles/" + filename);
        file.pipe(fstream);
        fstream.on("close", function () {
            var response = clone(baseResponse);
            response.status = SUCCESS;
            return res.end(JSON.stringify(response));
        });
    });
});
```

So what I am doing is getting the base64 from the canvas using `toDataURL()` and then convert it into a file object and then attaching it to the `FormData` object before uploading it to the server with `XMLHttpRequest`.

This method works for both Chrome and Firefox but not Safari. There is no error thrown anywhere at all. Does anyone knows why?

Comment: Why do you try to convert `data URI` to `File` object?

Comment: It's actually a requirement from the backend to send the image in a multipart/form-data. I tried adding the data URI to the formData and it doesn't work. Had to convert it to a file for it to be able to append it to the formData.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should not be an issue using `canvas.toBlob()` if there is no issue using `<input type=file>`. `File` object inherits from `Blob` object. `FormData` converts `Blob` to `File` object.

```
    canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
       var formData = new FormData();
       // `xhr` settings
const xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
       const formData = new window.FormData();
       // if you want to convert `blob` to `File`
       // const file = new window.File([blob], "signature.png", {type: blob.type});
       formData.append("file", blob /* or `file` */);
       xhr.open("POST", `${url}&documentType=${inputType}`);
       xhr.send(formData);
    }, "image/png")
```

Comment: thanks! this works! but there is no toBlob method on canvas in safari, had to add a polyfill for it.